# codeigniter random database row to android string

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, random, row

I have a website built with codeigniter that picks a random row from my "facts" table.
How to build an android app that simply displays this random fact, with a button to refresh/get a new fact?

ffotd_model.php:

```
 function getrandom_facts()
 {
  $this->db->order_by('id', 'RANDOM');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get('facts');
        return $result = $query->result();
 }
```

Controller   ffotd.php:

```
public function index()
    {
        $data   = array();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('header');
        $data['result'] = $this->ffotd_model->getrandom_facts();
        $this->load->view('ffotd.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

Comment: I don't know how to get the randomised fact to an android application

Comment: Right but your code doesn't do that? Is there an error?

Comment: "$this->load->view('ffotd.php', $data);" no need for the .php here, just ffotd will do.

Comment: This code is just for the web part. I don't know how to get it from working on the web, to inplemented in an android application

Comment: Do you know where to start with android development? What did you try so far?